# how to use pretrained model CNN with real images various size?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

how to use pretrained model on 512x512 images on real images with different sizes like Yolo object detection on real image ?

CNNs require fixed image sizes, so how do you manage to use the models on real images larger than the inputs?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just about the image size, you could resize your image to have same size as model input. When you receive the output, assuming that you have bounding boxes or locations etc, you can always rescale them back to original image size. Many ML/DL frameworks provide this functionality

Comment: I am trying as part of my internship to make a CNN to convert the R, G, B bands of UAV multispectral images into natural RGB images. My problem is that the input size of the network I'm doing is 512x512 and I don't know if resizing the UAV images from around 5000x3000 to 512x512 won't cause me to lose information?? how can I use it since the output image is the same size as the input.

Comment: Loosing information depends on your use case. There are models that could perform really good on 1024x1024 data. If you think resizing input and output images could cause an issue you should change network input/output sizes and perform a new training

Comment: ok i will try that. But won't the computing time and power increase exponentially for 1024x1024 images??

Comment: Yes. also network size increases, which means you will need more memory for inference

Comment: Ok. Sir do you know how Yolov7 does inference for large images ?